# Unable to load data in ExtJS tree grid - Only root node is visible

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs-grid, extjs-stores

I created a sample of ExtJS tree grid. But the grid is showing only the root node. Please check this [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/25v) and let me know why the remaining nodes are not visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you misspelled the property "children" (you have written "Children"). Correct that and you will see the children.

Also you might consider adding an ID for every node.

Comment: Thank you Andrei for quick reply. Check this example (http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/#!/example/tree/check-tree.html ) , even this example does not have ID column. I have also updated the fiddle to include ID but even then I am not getting the desired result.

Comment: WOW. That was fast. Changing Children to lower case helped. Thank you

Comment: System gave me error message saying, you cannot accept answer in 5 minutes. I love this site :)